# jQuery .map won't work properly sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built some Chrome extension that uses `$(".class").map(..)` function, but for some reason sometimes it won't find the element I am looking for..

This is my code:

```
var videocontent = $(".content").map(function () { if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("id=\"player_wrapper\"") > -1) { return this; } });
if(videocontent.length)
{
    // Success
}
else
    alert("ERROR");
```

There are multiple elements with class `.content` so I use `.map` to find the correct one.
Once every 10 times it attempts, it will alert an error because it didn't find it for some reason. I was trying multiple things but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(...).map()` isn't designed for searching for element, it is for applying a function to each element of an array to transform it somehow. You want to use `$(...).find()` instead:

```
var videocontent = $(".content").find('#player_wrapper');
```

https://api.jquery.com/find/

And it looks like you are then going up the tree to find it's parent, so:

```
var videocontent = $(".content").find('#player_wrapper').parent();
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I'll give it a try. It might speed up things a bit.

Comment: I tried it your way, but when I try `alert(videocontent.html());`, it says it's undefined.

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the original post? Though looking at your original sample again would `$('#player_wrapper').html()` not suffice?

Comment: @OmerAviv cool! See my last comment too. Can you also mark the answer accepted if you're problem has been solved? Thanks